# Exactly one/discriminated unions for react props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to define a typescript type for react component props. My component is a basic button that accepts either an `icon` prop, or a `text` prop. It can't have both, but must have one.

I was trying to start with a basic discriminated union, but it doesn't work like expected:

```
interface TextButtonProps extends TypedButtonProps {
  text: string
}

interface IconButtonProps extends TypedButtonProps {
  icon: JSX.Element
}

export const Button = ({ onClick, ...props }: IconButtonProps | TextButtonProps): JSX.Element => {
//...
```

When I use that component elsewhere, TS doesn't throw any errors:

`<Button icon={<IconClose />} text='test' uiVariant='default' />`

Following an article I found online, describing the interfaces with optional properties and *never* works:

```
interface TextButtonProps extends TypedButtonProps {
  text?: string
  icon?: never
}

interface IconButtonProps extends TypedButtonProps {
  icon?: JSX.Element
  text?: never
}
```

All of my uses of `<Button>` will throw an error if both `icon` and `text` exist.

Why does that work? I'm not thrilled with how verbose it is - if I add more button types I have to add those new properties to every single interface.

My second issue is that because the properties are *optional*, I can get away with not defining **either** icon or text prop - remember I need to ensure one or the other exists.

Is there a cleaner solution that would satisfy my needs?

Comment: I have an `Either` utility type that I use in cases like this.  On my phone now but I can answer later.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPzn5N)?

Comment: FWIW this isn't truly a React specific question, you would have this issue calling any function that takes a union type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, to require one but not both, only mark the `never` property optional:

```
interface TextButtonProps extends TypedButtonProps {
  text: string
  icon?: never
}

interface IconButtonProps extends TypedButtonProps {
  icon: JSX.Element
  text?: never
}
```

If TS ever adds support for exact object types like Flow has, then maybe you would be able to get the errors you want without the optional `never` props.  But [the feature request for exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) has been open for a long time...

Another option would be to make separate components that delegate to the underlying `Button`:

```
export const IconButton = (props: IconButtonProps) => <Button {...props} />
export const TextButton = (props: TextButtonProps) => <Button {...props} />
```

Then TS excess property checking would work - in most cases.  It's important to keep in mind that excess property checking isn't perfect, it doesn't guarantee soundness like exact object types would.

Answer (score 2):

[*Discriminated union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) is probably misleading here: a such discriminated union is based on a *discriminant property*, which takes a *unique literal* value, one per type in the union, thus making it explicit which type you handle, as shown in [vighnesh153's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75077615/5108796).

But here you do not want such discriminant property.

---

> Why does that work?

No type is assignable to [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#the-never-type), therefore trying to define the prop/key with any type (other than `never` or `undefined`) is an error.

This effectively forbids passing a defined prop/key with that name.

---

> because the properties are optional, I can get away with not defining either icon or text prop

As explained in [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75077800/5108796), only the forbidden `never` type properties should be made optional. You can keep the other properties required.

---

> how verbose it is - if I add more button types I have to add those new properties to every single interface.

We can make some helper type to factorize the code. I guess that is what [LindaPaiste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75077554/exactly-one-discriminated-unions-for-react-props/75077978#comment132489504_75077554) refers to in their comment on the question, and I will let them describe their own solution, as it sounds an interesting general helper!

In the meantime, and specific to your case, you could first build a type that forbids *all* specific props, so that you can use it on each button type, [omitting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) the specific props so they become legal:

```
// List all specific props to be forbidden
type ButtonSpecificProps = 'text' | 'icon' | 'other' | 'otherCombined' | 'otherOptional'

// Mapped type to convert the list (union of literals) into forbidden keys of an object
type NeverButtonSpecificProps = {
    //^? { text?: undefined; icon?: undefined; other?: undefined; otherCombined?: undefined; otherOptional?: undefined }
    [P in ButtonSpecificProps]?: never
}

type OnlyButtonProps<T> = T // Legal specific props
    & Omit<NeverButtonSpecificProps, keyof T> // Forbidden props, except for legal ones
    & TypedButtonProps // Other common props

type TextButtonProps = OnlyButtonProps<{
    text: string
}>

type IconButtonProps = OnlyButtonProps<{
    icon: JSX.Element
}>

// You can have several legal props simultaneously, possibly some optional
type OtherButtonProps = OnlyButtonProps<{
    other: string
    otherCombined: boolean
    otherOptional?: number
}>

export const Button = ({ onClick, ...props }: IconButtonProps | TextButtonProps | OtherButtonProps) => {
    //...
    return null
}

() => (
    <>
        {/* Types of property 'text' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. */}
        <Button icon={<div />} text='test' uiVariant='default' />

        {/* Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (TextButtonProps | IconButtonProps | OtherButtonProps)'. */}
        <Button />

        <Button text='foo' />

        <Button icon={<div />} />

        {/* Property 'otherCombined' is missing in type '{ other: string; }' but required in type '{ other: string; otherCombined: boolean; otherOptional?: number | undefined; }'. */}
        <Button other='foo' />

        <Button other='foo' otherCombined={true} />

        <Button other='foo' otherCombined={true} otherOptional={2} />
    </>
)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgBUBPMJAEwCEBXGDAjUACjjABnOAG9yceXGEBhADbA0AawD8ALjh9qG6hADu1OQr7AAaiijAUtXXADkXJIz4qYL8gF9KAHpAuAAZYAl4FBUVOAlONGBMdTgwcSkhOAAjZkxoLOAud3MYDmZ+QWEAZQSk9TEISTgAXlc6AA8fOAAfV3VhFx7XCBgAC3pB3pcR8aglXALqbknhsfoAeTAYYGFo33JguABZFDBOLjhSzkuIODRhADd6eDW4NUi4AAoDHepFTDewDoUGiEgAlHAaJk8lACkUkH8NEg2FIIADHIosgArJAYchXZgAOSQTygFSE1BquLqaAaTVasgUcGCAD0tBZ5ABtESQv7k6q1ZK09IAXWcS1J-koBLg62oKjY-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)

Comment: I appreciate the detail you went into, that explains a lot. I may return to this approach for more complex cases, but for today, Andy's question solves it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include a common property in both interfaces, whose value is different in each of them. Learn more about [Discriminating unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)

```
interface ButtonProps {
  onClick?: (e: Event) => void;
}

interface IconButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  type: 'icon-button';
  icon: React.ReactElement;
}

interface TextButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  type: 'text-button';
  text: string;
}

function Button(props: IconButtonProps | TextButtonProps) {
  return null
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button type="icon-button" icon={<div />} />
      <Button type="text-button" text="text" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works, but having to add an extra prop to get it working negates the benefit. Might as well make a separate component entirely called `IconButton`